# C# String literal with concatenation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET C# application, and I frequently use the verbatim string literal such as

```
dbCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO MYTABLE (COLUMN, COLUMN2)
                          VALUES ('data', 'data)";
```

This is all great, but when I try to concatenate the string with a variable such as

```
dbCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO MYTABLE" + Session["table_extension"] + "(COLUMN, COLUMN2)
                          VALUES('data','data')";
```

I get an error stating Newline in constant.  How can I avoid this while still using the @ string literal?

Comment: Aren't you missing a second `@` symbol? `dbCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO MYTABLE" + Session["table_extension"] + @"(COLUMN, COLUMN2)
                          VALUES('data','data')";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the @ in front of the second string literal or use String.Format()

Answer (score 2):

1) Don't concatenate strings to build SQL commands, it's really dangerous and error phrone (see SQL Injection: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

You should use ADO.NET parameters (http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06)

2) If you are going to concatenate strings, use string.Format like:

```
var sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO MyTable ('col1') VALUES ({0})", col1Value);
```

Or use the new simplified syntax which has a better compile time check:

```
var sql = $"INSERT INTO MyTable (col1) VALUES ('{col1Value}')";
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you!

```
dbCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO MYTABLE" + Session["table_extension"].ToString() + "(COLUMN, COLUMN2)
                      VALUES('data','data')";
```